# Angular [href] new tab in browser

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an a href that I would like to open in an new tab windows but I am getting an error Attribute is allowed only when 'href' is present.

> Is there a better way to do this in Angular?

```
        <td class="grid-archive-column_name">
            <a target="_blank"  [href]="getTemplateHref(item.VersionKey)">{{item.TemplateName}}</a>
        </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **routerLink** instead of href

```
 <a target="_blank"  [routerLink]="getTemplateHref(item.VersionKey)">{{item.TemplateName}}</a>
```

Comment: @Jefferson You have to import router module

Answer (score 0):

You can try window.open method on link giving href attribute # value.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but could use interpolation as follows:

```
<a target="_blank" href="{{getTemplateHref(item.VersionKey)}}">{{item.TemplateName}}</a>
```

This was a better solution in my situation.